# Yii: cannot get the relations

Tags: php, yii, conditional-statements

My Model:

RetailItem:

```
public function relations()
{
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
                    'retailItemDetail' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Item', array('item_id' => 'id')),
        );
}
```

My view:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
//$criteria->condition= "item_id = $id";
$items = RetailItem::model()->findAll($criteria);

CVarDumper::dump($items[0],3,true);
```

And Result:

```
......
[relations] => array()
......
```

Why the relations `array()` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Here example:

```
//sql
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO transaction (id, userId) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO transaction (userId) VALUES (1);

//models
class User2 extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
    //... etc
} 

class Transaction2 extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'transaction';
    }


    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User2', 'userId'),
        );
    }
    //... etc
}
```

How to use:

```
$test = Transaction2::model()->findAll();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test[0]->user);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Comment: Sorry I want to get some data just like $items[0]->retailItemDetail->description . But I can't. I don't know what's wrong with it because I have try to copy the relations to another model, and run correctly.

Comment: **item_id** it is column in _RetailItemDetail_, **id** it is column in _Item_ is it right?

Comment: Yes, item_id is the column in RetailItem model. I used the same method in another model, it's work. but I can't use the same relation function is RetailItem model.

Comment: I can get all the data in the model except relations. It make my frustrated.

Comment: Check my answer. It is must work if **item_id** column in **RetailItem model**.

Comment: I updated the answer. Above 2 test tables with data and 2 models. It is works fine. I think your problem in data or in column name. Just attentively check your structure and data.